# .get() is not working for an object in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

`.get()` is not working for an object in TypeScript. In HTML I am unable to access the `max` value of the `dataFormparams` object.

```
export interface FormBUilderParams extends Object {  
    required: boolean;
    minlength: number;
    maxlength: number;
    regx: string
  }
 dataFormparams!: FormBUilderParams;

 Object.defineProperty(this.dataFormparams, "element.controllName", {
   required: element.required,
   minlength: element.minlength,
   maxlength: element.maxlength,
   regx: element.regx
   });
```

```html
<mat-hint align="start">Min {{dataFormparams.get('name').minlength}} and Max {{dataFormparams.get('name').maxlength} Characters</mat-hint>
```

Comment: There is no `get()` defined neither on the interface nor when using `Object.defineProperty()`. Nothing in this code suggests `.get()` should ever work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve. You can use `dataFormparams.minlength` directly . What is `get('name')` supposed to do in your understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use this way**

```
reactiveForm: FormGroup;

this.reactiveForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    email: [null, [
        Validators.required,
    ]
});

// convenience getter for easy access to form fields
get f() { return this.reactiveForm.controls; }
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `element.controllName` has a value of `"name"`, and you're trying to access that property. It would be like this:

Lose the quotations

```js
 Object.defineProperty(this.dataFormparams, element.controllName, {
   required: element.required,
   minlength: element.minlength,
   maxlength: element.maxlength,
   regx: element.regx
   });
```

Square brackets to look for a property given a string, question mark to prevent undefined errors.

```html
<mat-hint align="start">Min {{dataFormparams['name']?.minlength}} and Max {{dataFormparams['name']?.maxlength} Characters</mat-hint>
```